# Bison error output

Tags: bison

I'm using Bison and I've generated a quite complex grammar. The trouble is that my first test case is failing- but Bison will only say "syntax error". Is there any way to ask Bison to output the rule that failed to match and the token that is a problem? I used

```
%define parse.trace true
```

but still only get `syntax error` as the output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None of the Yacc-based parsers does anything much better than 'syntax error' when there is a problem; it is largely up to you to improve on that.

There are a couple of things you can do fairly readily.

One is to instrument your lexical analyzer so it prints out the tokens it finds as it returns them to the parser proper.  This tells you which token the grammar is failing on, and what tokens were supplied beforehand.

The other is to compile with Yacc debug enabled, and then turn it on.  This requires `-DYYDEBUG=1` and setting the variable `yydebug` to a non-zero value (conventionally 1).  The first step compiles the extra information into the grammar; the second step enables the output.

From the Bison 2.4.3 manual:

> #### §8.2 Tracing Your Parser
>
> If a Bison grammar compiles properly but doesn’t do what you want when it runs, the
>   yydebug parser-trace feature can help you figure out why.
>
> There are several means to enable compilation of trace facilities:
>
> - the macro `YYDEBUG`
>
>   Define the macro `YYDEBUG` to a nonzero value when you compile the parser.
>     This is compliant with POSIX Yacc. You could use `-DYYDEBUG=1` as a compiler
>     option or you could put `#define YYDEBUG 1` in the prologue of the grammar
>     file (see Section 3.1.1 [The Prologue], page 47).
> - the option `-t`, `--debug`
>
>   Use the `-t` option when you run Bison (see Chapter 9 [Invoking Bison],
>     page 117). This is POSIX compliant too.
> - the directive `%debug`
>
>   Add the `%debug` directive (see Section 3.7.12 [Bison Declaration Summary],
>     page 72). This is a Bison extension, which will prove useful when Bison will
>     output parsers for languages that don’t use a preprocessor. Unless POSIX and
>     Yacc portability matter to you, this is the preferred solution.
>
> We suggest that you always enable the debug option so that debugging is always possible.
>
> The trace facility outputs messages with macro calls of the form `YYFPRINTF (stderr,
>   format, args)` where `format` and `args` are the usual `printf` format and variadic arguments.
>   If you define `YYDEBUG` to a nonzero value but do not define `YYFPRINTF`, `<stdio.h>`
>   is automatically included and `YYFPRINTF` is defined to `fprintf`.
>
> Once you have compiled the program with trace facilities, the way to request a trace is
>   to store a nonzero value in the variable `yydebug`. You can do this by making the C code do
>   it (in main, perhaps), or you can alter the value with a C debugger.
>
> Each step taken by the parser when `yydebug` is nonzero produces a line or two of trace
>   information, written on `stderr`. The trace messages tell you these things:
>
> - Each time the parser calls `yylex`, what kind of token was read.
> - Each time a token is shifted, the depth and complete contents of the state stack (see
>     Section 5.5 [Parser States], page 95).
> - Each time a rule is reduced, which rule it is, and the complete contents of the state
>     stack afterward.

Comment: Outputting the tokens in yylex() was the winrar for me.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `%error-verbose` directive to help you out. It will give you a hint of which tokens the parser was expecting. Note that there may be more than one potential rule that has failed to match.

Comment: Bison recommends `%define parse.error verbose` now instead, however the above does still work!

Answer (score 2):

If you set the global variable `yydebug` to a nonzero value, bison will output debugging information as it's running that contains information about what the parse stack looks like, what state it's in, what rules it's using, etc.  It's how I usually go about debugging these sorts of errors.

Answer (score 2):

There is a confusion here.

`"%define parse.trace"` is exactly the same as `"%debug"`: it instruments the generated parser for runtime traces, showing the parser at work (but you still have to set the `yydebug` variable, see the documentation kindly reproduced by Jonathan Leffler).

For error messages to be more accurate (on this regard Jonathan is wrong), Bison *can* do better, thanks to `"%define error-verbose"`, as reported by Alek.